# regex to get strings between content generated by ckeditor, for server-end

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, markup, domparser

I am trying to get a regex that matches the strings between this output

```
<p>save</p>
<p>11<br />\nabc<br />\nabc<br />\nhello</p>\n\n<p>dfcs dcsd</p>\n\n<p>sdcsd<br />\nsdcsdc<br />\nsdcd</p>\n
<p>1</p>\n\n<p>11<br />\n111</p>\n\n<p>1111<br />\n11111</p>\n\n<p>1</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n
```

expected output:

```
1) save
2) 11
3) abc
4) hello
5) dfcs dcsd
6) sdcsd
7) sdcsdc
8) 1
9) 11
10) 111
11) 1111
12) 11111
13) 1
```

EDIT-
I am getting this html string generated from ckeditor in frontend, and sending it to node-backend where i need to extract text properly.

Comment: Is it litterally `\n` or is it a new line?

Comment: Do you need the numbers? I mean should `1) ` , `2) ` and so on be in the desired output? Your output seems to be the HTML view of the HTML source itself (where `\n` represents a real new line and not the text) and where you've got rid of the blank characters and lines. Then you added the line number prefixes.

Comment: @AnkurSingh ... Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more details but I would take the rendered HTML and then split it with this regex: `/(?:\s*\r?\n\s*)+/`

This will give you an array of lines (and remove a few empty chars around).

Then remove the empty lines and then loop over them to have your numbered lines.

The code below and result in the console:

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let renderedHtml = body.innerText;
let lines = renderedHtml.split(/(?:\s*\r?\n\s*)+/);

// Get rid of empty lines.
lines = lines.filter((line) => {
  return !line.match(/^\s*$/);
});

console.log(lines);

let output = '';

lines.forEach((line, i) => {
  output += (i + 1) + ') ' + line + "\n";
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<p>save</p>
<p>11<br />
abc<br />
abc<br />
hello</p>

<p>dfcs dcsd</p>

<p>sdcsd<br />
sdcsdc<br />
sdcd</p>

<p>1</p>

<p>11<br />
111</p>

<p>1111<br />
11111</p>

<p>1</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Note** ... since the OP did mention ... "for server-end" ... the OP most probably needs to [find a package](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords%3Adomparser&ranking=maintenance) which comes close to a browser's native [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) Web API.*

One approach was to use a mix of a parsed markup's (via [DOMParser.parseFromString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)) `innerText` string value and a multiline [capturing](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) regex like e.g. [`/^(?:\\n|\s)*(?<content>.*)/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/4bzz4m/1) together with [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and an additional [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) / [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) task.

```js
const htmlMarkup =
`<p>save</p>
<p>11<br />\nabc<br />\nabc<br />\nhello</p>\n\n<p>dfcs dcsd</p>\n\n<p>sdcsd<br />\nsdcsdc<br />\nsdcd</p>\n
<p>1</p>\n\n<p>11<br />\n111</p>\n\n<p>1111<br />\n11111</p>\n\n<p>1</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/4bzz4m/1]
const regXLineContent = /^(?:\\n|\s)*(?<content>.*)/gm;

const doc = (new DOMParser)
  .parseFromString(htmlMarkup, "text/html");

console.log(
  '... inner text ...',
  doc
    .body
    .innerText
);
console.log(
  '... list of pure content ...',
  Array
    .from(
      doc
        .body
        .innerText
        .matchAll(regXLineContent)
    )
    .map(match => match.groups.content)
    .filter(content => content !== '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Another, preferred approach, was to use a content [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting regex like ... [`/\n(?:\\n|\s)*/g`](https://regex101.com/r/4bzz4m/2) ... for directly getting an array of (valid) line contents.

Yet, as for the provided markup sample, and like with the former approach, one still needs to run the sanitizing `filter` task.

```js
const htmlMarkup =
`<p>save</p>
<p>11<br />\nabc<br />\nabc<br />\nhello</p>\n\n<p>dfcs dcsd</p>\n\n<p>sdcsd<br />\nsdcsdc<br />\nsdcd</p>\n
<p>1</p>\n\n<p>11<br />\n111</p>\n\n<p>1111<br />\n11111</p>\n\n<p>1</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/4bzz4m/2]
const regXLineSeparators = /\n(?:\\n|\s)*/g;

const doc = (new DOMParser)
  .parseFromString(htmlMarkup, "text/html");

console.log(
  '... inner text ...',
  doc
    .body
    .innerText
);
console.log(
  '... list of splitted content ...',
  doc
    .body
    .innerText
    .split(regXLineSeparators)
);
console.log(
  '... list of pure content ...',
  doc
    .body
    .innerText
    .split(regXLineSeparators)
    .filter(content => content !== '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```